# Uploading a file to GCP using signed-url, to a domain-named bucket is giving SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file to a GCP bucket using signed-url.

I was able to do this well in a normal bucket. But recently I changed my bucket to a domain-named bucekt(Eg: abc.somename.io)

Now when I'm trying to upload a file to this new bucket, after creating a signed-url, it is giving me the following error:

```
Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: 
Host: abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com. is not in the cert's altnames: 
DNS:*.storage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.commondatastorage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.content-storage-download.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.content-storage-upload.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.content-storage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.storage-download.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.storage-upload.googleapis.com, 
DNS:*.storage.select.googleapis.com, 
DNS:commondatastorage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:storage.googleapis.com, 
DNS:storage.select.googleapis.com, 
DNS:unfiltered.news
```

The generated signed-url is something like:

```
https://abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder3/image.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SH...
```

And I'm giving a PUT request to this URL.

When I tried the same PUT request through `curl -k` command, it worked fine.
What could be the issue here. Is it some kind of bug in GCP, which is considering the hostname to be different because of `.` in the bucket-name(in the url) ?

EDIT: Adding trace for both curl commands.

curl -k which worked successfully had following trace(changed/removed some of the keys):

```
*   Trying 2404:6800:4003:c04::80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com (0000:0000:4003:d04::80) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.storage.googleapis.com
*  start date: Jul  7 07:56:34 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 29 07:56:34 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x56268ff08580)
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> PUT folder1/folder2/folder3/folder3/image.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-S....(**removed**)
> Host: abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 4
> 
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/2 200 
< x-guploader-uploadid: AAANsUl9xW3changedfnX1wL_ggsyN-8_Cqk64UliOcchangedchangedchangedC7rCmWKteeuA
< etag: "changed"
< x-goog-generation: 000000000
< x-goog-metageneration: 1
< x-goog-hash: eeee=eeee==
< x-goog-hash: md5=kjbkjbkjbkjbkjb==
< x-goog-stored-content-length: 4
< x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
< vary: Origin
< content-length: 0
< date: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 06:19:28 GMT
< server: UploadServer
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
< 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection #0 to host abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com left intact
```

trace for normal curl command which failed:

```
*   Trying 2404:6800:4003:c04::80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com (2404:6800:4003:c04::80) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=*.storage.googleapis.com
*  start date: Jul  7 07:56:34 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 29 07:56:34 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com'
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com'
```

Comment: Hello, can you share the complete error trace and confirm if you are using the cli?

Comment: Wildcard certificates only support a single subdomain name. You cannot use `abc.somename.io.storage.googleapis.com`. You must use a single name such as `somename.storage.googleapis.com`. Check if your curl command (which you say works) is following a redirection. Show the entire command and output trace (add `--verbose`).

Comment: I have updated the questions with trace. And yes i tried curl commands using cli.

Comment: The -k option means `This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.`. Your curl command is not working either. Go back to my comment about subdomain name depth.

Comment: The issue got fixed. Actually while generating the signed_url, i was using `host = '{}.storage.googleapis.com'.format(self.__bucket_name)`. But turns out that while using domain-named buckets, we should just use host name as the domain name. i.e`abc.example.com/...` instead of `abc.example.com.storage.googleapis.com/...`

Comment: Hi, could you share how you fix this issue as an answer? This could will help to another users with the same problem